# Eigenvalues problem for the Laplacian operator on a free domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-transform

I want to ask a question about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors if they exist for the following question:
$$ - \Delta u = \lambda u{\text{  x}} \in \mathbb{R}$$
I have tried to do the Fourier transform of both side of the equation, I got
$$({\xi ^2} - \lambda )\hat u = 0{\text{ }}\xi  \in \mathbb{R}$$
then, I can not go further than that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "Dirichlet" in the title but haven't said anything about boundary conditions... in case, certainly
$$-u''(x) = \lambda u(x)$$
can be solved for $u$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for any $\lambda$. This is a standard linear second-order homogeneous ODE. For background on how to solve these, see for instance [this chapter](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-2ndOrderLinearEqns_Stu.pdf) of Stewart.

For $\lambda\geq 0$ the solutions are
$$u(x) = Ae^{ix\sqrt{\lambda}} + Be^{-ix\sqrt{\lambda}}$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $A,B$ are arbitrary constants. You can apply Euler's formula to extract the real solutions,
$$u(x) = C\cos\left(x\sqrt{\lambda}\right) + D\sin\left(x\sqrt{\lambda}\right)$$
for real constants $C,D$.

For $\lambda <0$ instead the real solutions are
$$u(x) = Ce^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}} + De^{-x\sqrt{-\lambda}}.$$

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the answer, I did a mistake in the title, I want to know how to solve the above problem without any boundary conditions, on a free domain.

Comment: @Gustave Well, the above shows the solutions to $\Delta u = -\lambda u$ on a free domain (for $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$). These may or may not be the eigenfunctions you're looking for, depending on precisely what Hilbert space you're considering, etc.

Comment: Thanks sir, let us say that  $u$ is in $L^2$ space,  can wa expect something interesting?